# I want to print out values of which follows 2347=value in logfile. Please note that place of 2347 isnt fixed so cant use cut -d

Tags: unix, awk

UNIX--

I  want to print out values of following `tag 2347` in the format below `2347=value` in log file. Please note that place of `2347` isn't fixed so cant use cut -d .  tried using `awk` but no luck

```
cat filename | awk '{for (I=1;I<=NF;I++) if ($I == "/2347=/") {print $(I+1)};}'
```

sample log file- Please note that tag 2347 position isnt fixed. so cut -d cant be used.
log.20200723.log.bz2: <1345 OrderSingle (8=FIX.4.29=30235=D34=134549=FLN50=BB52=20200723-08:30:11.16856=UAT57=ALGO115=ROB116=BB1=Multi2347=RAA0010-2020072322=248=633517115=JPY21=138=2040=154=155=8306.JP65=JP100=XTKS109=Rotterdam60=20200723-08:30:10.40120013=IS8DZW1TZSQ8YPXVRC46847=16528=Y6523=Y6207=56520=06243=06245=010=099)

Sample log :

```
OrderSingle (8=FIX.4.29=30235=D34=134549=FLN50=BB52=20200723-08:30:11.16856=UAT57=ALGO115=ROB116=BB1=Multi2347=RAA0010-2020072322=248=633517115=JPY21=138=2040=154=155=8306.JP65=JP100=XTKS109=Rotterdam60=20200723-08:30:10.40120013=IS8DZW1TZSQ8YPXVRC46847=16528=Y6523=Y6207=56520=06243=06245=010=099).
```

Comment: Could you please post sample of input and expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: If your inputfile has `2347=value` then the condition `$I == "/2347=/"` will never match.  Something like `$I ~ /2347=/` will match. But indeed some sample data will be needed if this is really what you want to do.

Comment: Hi Luk, Below is one sample part (1000's of them are there in the log) of log.20200723.log.bz2:  <1345 OrderSingle (8=FIX.4.29=30235=D34=134549=FLN50=BB52=20200723-08:30:11.16856=UAT57=ALGO115=ROB116=BB1=Multi2347=RAA0010-2020072322=248=633517115=JPY21=138=2040=154=155=8306.JP65=JP100=XTKS109=Rotterdam60=20200723-08:30:10.40120013=IS8DZW1TZSQ8YPXVRC46847=16528=Y6523=Y6207=56520=06243=06245=010=099).Also pleas note that the position of 2347 isnt fixed so I cant use cut -d option. I will need to find 2347= throughout the log and find out value next to= equal to sign

Comment: Cyrus told you to do this: "Please take a look at [editing-help[(http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)"   Is that really difficult to do ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
grep -o '2347=[^=]*'
```

Demo:

```
$ echo "(8=FIX.4.29=30235=D34=134549=FLN50=BB52=20200723-08:30:11.16856=UAT57=ALGO115=ROB116=BB1=Multi2347=RAA0010-2020072322=248=633517115=JPY21=138=2040=154=155=8306.JP65=JP100=XTKS109=Rotterdam60=20200723-08:30:10.40120013=IS8DZW1TZSQ8YPXVRC46847=16528=Y6523=Y6207=56520=06243=06245=010=099)" | grep -o '2347=[^=]*' 
2347=RAA0010-2020072322
$
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But my request snt matching with ur solution. I have provided detailed explaination in the comment section.

Comment: I have updated answer based on input provided

Comment: Thanks Diggvijay! This worked perfectly. Now uderstand this part [^=]* ^= means start with equal to

Comment: No. inside `[]` it means negate. '[^=]` means any char except `=`

Comment: thanks digvijay!it worked like a charm.